# How can I "continue" a loop in the calling function, from the called function?

Tags: python, function, try-except, continue

I have the following working code:

```
while True:
    try:
        pyautogui.click('a.png')
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
        print('a not found')
        continue
    try:
        pyautogui.click('b.png')
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
        print('b not found')
        continue
```

I want to be able to do it like this instead:

```
def a():
    try:
        pyautogui.click('a.png')
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
        print('a not found')
        continue
        
def b():
    try:
        pyautogui.click('b.png')
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
        print('b not found')
        continue
        
while True:
    a()
    b()
```

I can't use "continue" when I put the try-except block inside the function. I want it to run until I click on the image it is trying to click while inside the function. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You can't use ```continue``` the way you're trying to use it. A better approach would be to have ```a()``` and ```b()``` return a value that indicates that the main ```while``` loop should continue or terminate.

Comment: I know I can't use it, unfortunately I couldn't understand what you're trying to say, I don't know much about the functions, can you be more descriptive?

Comment: `try`/`except` (not "expect") is **not a loop**. The reason you can't use `continue` there isn't because "it's inside a function" - you absolutely can use `continue` inside a function - but because there is no loop to continue. In the working code that you show, there is no need for `continue` statements; all they do right now is ensure that if `a.png` is not found, the next *attempt* will also be on `a.png` rather than `b.png` (because the loop starts over from the top).

Comment: It seems like what you are trying to do is have a function control the behaviour of the code that called it. It doesn't work that way. The calling code has to make the decision about its own behaviour. It can *use information* that it gets from calling the function, for example, the `return` value.

Comment: I tried to edit the question to be more useful as a search target for others, because I think the underlying question is good and allows for explaining an important technique.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If "a" is not found anyway, I want the next try to be "a" again, but I can't do it using a function

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain that in the question. thank you for edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've failed to program your loop logic.  If I interpret your description properly, you want to alternate between clicking on the two areas, and to stay in the loop until you get a successful click on either one.

If so, please look again at your code: what causes you to leave the loop?  Note that it's not possible to control the loop logic directly from within a function: the function has no way to know that it's being called from inside a loop.  Instead, have the function return its success status:

```
def a():
    try:
        pyautogui.click('a.png')
        return True
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
        return False

# Do the same with function `b`

found = False
while not found:
    found = a() or b()
```

This last line is a typical programming idiom for trying things in a particular order.  It depends on Boolean short-circuit logic.  The run-time system will call `a()`; it that comes back `True`, then it knows that the entire expression will be `True`, and doesn't bother calling `b()`.  If the call to `a` comes back `False`, only then will the interpreter call `b()`, assign that return value to `found`.

In fact, you could reduce the loop to

```
while not a() and not b():
    pass
```

---

RESPONSE AFTER OP DISCREPANCY

If all you need is to repeatedly click on each picture, until each is found then your loop logic does not match what you need.  This makes the problem much simpler:

```
while not a():
    pass
while not b():
    pass
```

Comment: this code running "b" after "a" failing in this code. I want it to run "a" after failing "a" until it succeeds.

Comment: Switch `and` for `or` and vice-versa, and it should work as you describe.

Comment: @EmreOz  Your posted code very clearly makes *one* attempt at each of `a` and `b` in turn.  If you want something else, please update your question and your attempt to reflect that need.  What your comment describes is two successive loops.

Comment: @Prune Can I do something to make "a" succeed 7 times and then execute "b"?

Comment: Of course you can -- but that is yet another issue.  It seems that you need to do more work on learning basic Python control structures, as well as practicing programming with those structures.  Tutoring you one step at a time is out of scope for this site -- or any site, really.

Comment: @Prune Sorry for the extra request, but since I wrote the code on the one hand, I may come across new things.

Comment: @Prune You're right, I'll take what you say into consideration.